# Button added as an annotation view subview not working?

Tags: ios, swift, uibutton, mapkit, mkannotationview

I have added a subview to the annotation view on `didSelect` method of the map and it’s working as expected(screenshot). I have a button inside the popup, and it's active and user-interaction enabled, but I am not getting the button action?

I did a view debugging and it seems the button is on top of the view stack.

```
func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
    DispatchQueue.main.async {        
        view.addSubview(self.popupView)
    }
}
```

This action method is inside the `Popupview`

```
@IBAction func actionTapPickup(_ sender: UIButton) {
   print("button tapped)
}
```

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You have declared your `actionTapPickup` as an `@IBAction`.

- Did you really instantiate this view from a NIB or storyboard designed in Interface Builder? If so, make sure you hooked up your `@IBAction` successfully? Are you instantiating this view from the `NIB` (rather than programmatically)?
- If, on the other hand, you created this subview programmatically, you wouldn’t use the `@IBAction` qualifier, but rather just mark it as `@objc` and then manually add the the target for the `.touchUpInside` event:

  ```
  button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
  ```

If you let us know whether you’re instantiating this custom popup/callout programmatically or via a NIB, we can outline this in a little more detail. (My example, below, is the programmatic implementation.)

Bottom line, the hooking up a button in a custom callout is much like hooking up a button anywhere. Use `@IBAction` for IB designed views, and use `@objc` and `addTarget` for programmatically created buttons.

---

As an aside, once you have your immediate problem behind you, it’s worth noting that there are subtle issues in getting custom callouts to work properly. The [Location Awareness Programming Guide: Creating Callouts](https://developer.apple.com/library/archive/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/LocationAwarenessPG/AnnotatingMaps/AnnotatingMaps.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40009497-CH6-SW28) outlines this, but unfortunately the examples are in Objective-C. Anyway, the behavior we want is:

- if you tap elsewhere on the map (i.e. deselect the annotation view), the callout should disappear; but however
- if you tap on the annotation view’s custom callout (but not on its button), you *don’t* want that to deselect the annotation.

To achieve this, it largely can be distilled down to two not-entirely-obvious little tricks:

1. Add a `hitTest` for the annotation view that includes a test for hit in. the custom callout. This is to ensure that the annotation isn’t deselected when you tap in the callout.
2. Add a button behind the whole callout, so that it consumes any touches that miss your “pickup in 60 minutes” button, but are still in the callout.

Thus:

```
// let’s assume we have an annotation for our pickup location

class PickupLocationAnnotation: MKPointAnnotation {
    let hours: String

    init(hours: String) {
        self.hours = hours
        super.init()
    }
}

// let’s have a protocol for the callout to inform view controller that the “pickup” button was tapped

protocol CalloutViewDelegate: class {
    func calloutTapped(for annotation: MKAnnotation)
}

// Our callout view class

class CalloutView: UIView {
    weak var annotation: MKAnnotation?
    weak var delegate: CalloutViewDelegate?

    let button: UIButton = {
        let button = UIButton(type: .system)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        button.setTitle("Tap here to pickup in 60 Mins", for: .normal)
        button.addTarget(self, action: #selector(didTapButton(_:)), for: .touchUpInside)
        return button
    }()

    lazy var label: UILabel = {
        let label = UILabel()
        label.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        label.numberOfLines = 0
        label.text = (annotation as? PickupLocationAnnotation)?.hours
        return label
    }()

    init(annotation: MKAnnotation?, delegate: CalloutViewDelegate) {
        self.annotation = annotation
        self.delegate = delegate
        super.init(frame: .zero)
        configure()
    }

    required init?(coder: NSCoder) {
        fatalError("init(coder:) has not been implemented")
    }

    func configure() {
        addBackgroundButton(to: self)
        addSubview(button)
        addSubview(label)

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
            button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: 10),
            button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: label.topAnchor, constant: -10),

            label.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: leadingAnchor, constant: 10),
            label.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: trailingAnchor, constant: -10),
            label.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: bottomAnchor, constant: -10)
        ])

        layer.cornerRadius = 10
        layer.borderColor = UIColor.blue.cgColor
        layer.borderWidth = 2
        backgroundColor = .white
    }

    @objc func didTapButton(_ sender: Any) {
        if let annotation = annotation {
            delegate?.calloutTapped(for: annotation)
        }
    }

    fileprivate func addBackgroundButton(to view: UIView) {
        let button = UIButton(type: .custom)
        button.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        view.addSubview(button)
        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            button.topAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.topAnchor),
            button.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.bottomAnchor),
            button.leadingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.leadingAnchor),
            button.trailingAnchor.constraint(equalTo: view.trailingAnchor)
        ])
    }
}

// our annotation view for our pickup annotations

class PickupLocationAnnotationView: MKPinAnnotationView {
    weak var calloutView: UIView?

    override func prepareForDisplay() {
        super.prepareForDisplay()
        canShowCallout = false
    }

    // make sure that hits in callout are recognized as not-deselecting the annotation view

    override func hitTest(_ point: CGPoint, with event: UIEvent?) -> UIView? {
        if let hitView = super.hitTest(point, with: event) { return hitView }

        if let calloutView = calloutView {
            let point = convert(point, to: calloutView)
            return calloutView.hitTest(point, with: event)
        }

        return nil
    }

    // lets move the add callout here, inside the annotation view class,
    // so the annotation view can keep track of its callout

    func addCallout(delegate: CalloutViewDelegate) {
        removeCallout()

        let view = CalloutView(annotation: annotation, delegate: delegate)
        view.translatesAutoresizingMaskIntoConstraints = false
        addSubview(view)
        calloutView = view

        NSLayoutConstraint.activate([
            view.centerXAnchor.constraint(equalTo: centerXAnchor),
            view.bottomAnchor.constraint(equalTo: topAnchor, constant: -10)
        ])
    }

    func removeCallout() {
        calloutView?.removeFromSuperview()
    }
}

// random view controller example that adds an annotation

class ViewController: UIViewController {
    @IBOutlet weak var mapView: MKMapView!

    override func viewDidLoad() {
        super.viewDidLoad()

        let coordinate = CLLocationCoordinate2D(latitude: 37.332693, longitude: -122.03071)
        mapView.camera = MKMapCamera(lookingAtCenter: coordinate, fromDistance: 1_000, pitch: 0, heading: 0)
        mapView.register(PickupLocationAnnotationView.self, forAnnotationViewWithReuseIdentifier: MKMapViewDefaultAnnotationViewReuseIdentifier)

        let hours = """
            Mon to Thu 10am-7pm
            Fri 12pm-9pm
            Sat 10am-11pm
            """
        let annotation = PickupLocationAnnotation(hours: hours)
        annotation.coordinate = coordinate
        mapView.addAnnotation(annotation)
    }
}

// the selecting and deselecting of annotation views

extension ViewController: MKMapViewDelegate {
    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didSelect view: MKAnnotationView) {
        if let view = view as? PickupLocationAnnotationView {
            view.addCallout(delegate: self)
        }
    }

    func mapView(_ mapView: MKMapView, didDeselect view: MKAnnotationView) {
        if let view = view as? PickupLocationAnnotationView {
            view.removeCallout()
        }
    }
}

// the delegate conformance so view controller can know when the callout button was tapped

extension ViewController: CalloutViewDelegate {
    func calloutTapped(for annotation: MKAnnotation) {
        print(#function)
    }
}
```